# PhpStorm Xdebug : Waiting for incoming connection with ide key

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am running PHP 7.0 and PhpStorm 2016.1

I have x-debug installed and this is my configuration :

[image]

When running Debug form PhpStorm the Debugger tab shows this error message:

> Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '13136'

ide key varies every time. Please help.

Comment: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm 2) Post screenshots: how you debug (what you see in IDE); whole xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is incomplete as it lacks your current php settings for xdebug, but it looks like you do not have `idekey` configured (you see IDE Key to be reported as "*No value*" for that reason). Just add:

```
xdebug.idekey = ....
```

to your config. Here's working config from my setup:

```
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
xdebug.remote_start = on
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.idekey = "xdebug"
```

Value used for `idekey` can be any string you want but must be the same you set up in PHPStorm (see `Settings` / `Languages` / `PHP` / `Debug` / `DBGp Proxy` / `IDE Key`).

Comment: I have not setup any idekey in IDE. How do i do that ?

Comment: i added the Added the value to the IDE Key in PHPStorm but still its the same problem

Comment: You need configure both sides. And often restart httpd after the change.

Comment: Already did that, does not work. But i think i got the problem. Actually PHPStorm is picking the php.ini file for CLI but i think it should be picking the one for apache2. Howver i dont know how to change this and point PHPStorm to pick the right php.ini file.

Comment: Then alter the CLI's php.init. But PHP storm should be picking nothing really unless you are using built-in webserver - in such case I cannot help much more as I never used it (I use vagrant)

Comment: @AngryCoder *"Actually PHPStorm is picking the php.ini file for CLI but i think it should be picking the one for apache2"* -- PhpStorm does NOT pick up any php.ini -- it's PHP/your OS settings that decides what php.ini to use.