# "Waiting for incoming connection" | PhpStorm and xdebug

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I'm having some trouble with PhpStorm and xdebug (like some other people).

I seen, and tried:

[PhpStorm Xdebug : Waiting for incoming connection with ide key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183225/phpstorm-xdebug-waiting-for-incoming-connection-with-ide-key)

[PhpStorm, xdebug and vagrant still waiting for incoming connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096056/phpstorm-xdebug-and-vagrant-still-waiting-for-incoming-connection)

[Xdebug PhpStorm: Waiting for incoming connection with ide key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715128/xdebug-phpstorm-waiting-for-incoming-connection-with-ide-key)

When I start the debugger I go a url that ends with `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=XXXXXX`. This is the same ID that I have on `phpinfo()`.

My config:

**php.ini**

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.113
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.idkey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log =/Users/gustavelmgren/xdebug.log
```

**xdebug.log**

```
> Log opened at 2016-11-09 19:52:07 I: Connecting to configured
> address/port: 192.168.1.113:9001. I: Connected to client. :-)
> -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug"
> fileuri="file:///Users/gustavelmgren/dbwebb-kurser/anax-flat/htdocs/index.php"
> language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="19557"
> idekey="13691"><engine
> version="2.2.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick
> Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2014 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
```

**PhpStorm settings**

[image: DGBp Proxy]

[image: phpinfo - xdebug]

[image: Server]

[image: Debug conf]

Comment: I could only post two images. 

Here is the last two: 


[Server] -> [https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRMjs.png]

[Debug conf] -> [https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDjFP.png]

Comment: 1) What is the path to the file where breakpoint is set as seen in IDE? 2) Show a screenshot of the line with breakpoint 3) Please provide whole xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output (e.g. share it via Google Drive or similar) 4) Same with xdebug log -- the way how it shown here is pretty useless. 5) Please upgrade your xdebug -- please use at least 2.3.x (better latest 2.4.x) 6) You do not need DBGp Proxy -- it 's useful only in certain scenarios (e.g. for remote debug with multiple devs) 7) are IP & Port are correct? 8) Are you sure it's PhpStorm that listens on xdebug port?

Answer (score 0):

I was helped in the file by the **host**, remove the two lines

`":: 1" localhost (ipv6 (localhost)`

**phpstorm** did not see localhost ip v4)